# Unable to mount USB drive - not recognized by computer

Tags: usb, mount

I use a repurposed retired cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S#) as a media player, and have always been able to plug it in to my computer via USB cable to load new movies, songs, etc. Today, for the first time, my computer will not recognize the cell phone and I am unable to mount it. I've tried the remedies elsewhere on this site involving sudo fdisk -l; dmesg; mkdir; etc, but have been unsuccessful at fixing. Please advise. I am running linux 14.4. Thank you.

Comment: What is "linux 14.4"?

Comment: Cables go bad. How did you ensure the cable that you used is good?

Comment: Ubuntu version 14.4 (Trusty Tahr).

I'm pretty sure the cable is good since I was able to charge the cell phone to full charge on it just now.

Answer (score 0):

> Cables go bad. How did you ensure the cable that you used is good? – user535733>

That was it: the USB cable had a bad connector. It is able to send power to the device and recharge it, but not able to connect its data. Thanks for pointing that out. Problem solved.